# PHP - Insert form value from form select option into DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called **school** with a table called **persons**. On my PHP/HTML form I have a selector option with a drop down. I want to pass the value of the drop down  into my database.

I thought the below would work, single option is only available. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? DI feel I need to store the value somewhere but Im not sure its even been captured.

**index.php**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div><label for="Criticality">Criticality</label><select name="critical">
                    <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
                    <option value="Important">Important</option>
                    <option value="Support">Support</option>
                    <option value="Non Critical">Non Critical</option>
                </select></div>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "school");
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $critical = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['critical']);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons (critical) VALUES ('$critical')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
      header("Location: success.html");
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What you posted should work. Does anything echo at all? Do you get redirected?

Comment: Nothing at all, I check the db and theres a new entry but its empty, im a bit stuck

Comment: You are vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @LukeTo Add this `if(!empty($_POST)){print_r($_POST);}` at the top of the insert.php to get what is server recieving to process.